# Using forEach() in Gatling

Tags: foreach, gatling, scala-gatling

I have a scenario where I fetch some ItemBarcodes from Database. These are like this:

> 627729416990,627729416990,627729416990

I'm using split(",") to extract the individual items and saving it into Seq inside session.

> .exec{
>        session => 
>            itemBrcdSeq = data.split(",").toSeq
>        session
> }

I want to use these items in further requests as long as there are items present.

I tried directly sending the Seq into forEach() action but it didn't work:

> ```
> .foreach(itemBrcdSeq, "item"){
>   exec(...)
> }
> ```

Please someone help where I'm doing wrong..

Answer (score 2):

> I'm using split(",") to extract the individual items and saving it into Seq inside session.

Your code is broken. You don't store anything in the Session, you populate a global var (and too late).

```scala
.exec { session =>
  session.set("itemBrcdSeq", data.split(",").toSeq)
}.foreach("${itemBrcdSeq}", "item"){
  exec(...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using java i used `foreach().on()` like so:

```
 public static ChainBuilder doDownLoadThumbnails = exec(
                    foreach("#{thumbnailURLs}", "tnURL").on(
                            exec(http(transThumbnailDownload)
                                    .get("${tnURL}")
                                    .headers()
                                    .check(status().is(200).saveAs("httpStatus"))
                            )
                    ));
```